# Using bitmap getPixels, instead of bitmap getPixel returns different result?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an android app that read the pixels of a bitmap using `getPixel` and it was working except that it was using a lot of computing power. 
So I tried to use `getPixels` instead and saving all integers to an integer array `int[]`.
It reduced the computing time down to a third but the end result was completely different from before.

I don't know if `getPixels` returns integers in a different way or if I'm just missing something in my code.

Old Code (working):

```
    int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    for (int X = 0; X < bitmapWidth; X++) 
    {   

        for( int Y = 0; Y < bitmapHeight;Y++)
        {
            colorValue = Color.red(bitmap.getPixel(X,Y)); 

            //Making use of colorValue here

        }
    }
```

New Code (different result):

```
    int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    int[] intArray = new int[bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight()];
    bitmap.getPixels(intArray,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());


    for (int X = 0; X < bitmapWidth; X++) 
    {   


        for( int Y = 0; Y < bitmapHeight;Y++)
        {
            colorValue = Color.red(intArray[X*Y]); 

            //Making use of colorValue here

        }
    }
```

I know `intArray[X*Y]` will give me the `intArray[0]` when reading the first row and first column but if those are the only places that are affected, it doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indexing in wrong. You should be using `y*w + x` instead of `x*y`. So:

```
colorValue = Color.red(intArray[X + Y * bitmap.getWidth()]);
```

Comment: I actually just came to that conclusion and I feel so stupid that I for some reason though x*y actually would work. Thank you!